# Foiint: a mixture of fintop and oiint

Tags: tikz-styles, integral

With this code I tried to create a `\fooint`-integral latex symbol, but the result is not good. I mean:
1 In the equation (1) I created the symbol I required using `\!`--spaces and `centernot`, but soon abondoned.
1 In the equation (2) I used `TikZ--for--equations` and the result is ok but with an only problem: when I write some math text soon after, the effect product is not good: the text must be horizzontaly--alined with `foiint`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{centernot}

\title{Foiints}
\author{PUCK}
\date{22 February 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\fintop\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\oiint\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\;\fintop\qquad\centernot{\oiint}\qquad\oiint\rotatebox{300}{\big|}\qquad\fintop\qquad
\tikz{\node at (0,0) {$\displaystyle{\oiint}$};
\draw[thick] (-.2875,-.0875) -- (.25,.125);}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tikz{\node at (0,0) {$\displaystyle{\oiint}$};
\draw[thick] (-.2875,-.0875) -- (.25,.125);}abc
\end{equation}

With TikZ

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$\displaystyle{\oiint}$};
\draw[thick] (-.2875,-.0875) -- (.25,.125);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How could I solv my problem?

Thank you so much in advanced.

**First Edit.** I clear mu question: I'd like to create a `\foiint` latex--command using the best way possible and suitable for equation--environments. I admit that I am not expert in creating these commands. I apologise if my question was not much clear.

Comment: Could you try `\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base]{$\displaystyle\oiint$};` for the vertical alignment?

Comment: so your question is just how to lower the tikz so it matches `\ooint`? [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLR7w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash should be a zero width box so it can overwrite the integral sign. The trick is to `\vcenter` it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fooint}{\mathop{\!\vcenter{\hbox to 0pt{%
  \tikz{\draw[thick] (-.2875,-.0875) -- (.25,.125);}\hss
}}}\!\oiint}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x\oiint\quad x\fooint a \quad \fooint_X a \quad \fooint\limits_X a
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wht does \hss mean? Thx

Comment: @Puck Infinitely stretchable or shrinkable space. Placed at that position means that the contents stick right of the zero width box.